# Rails - No method error when trying to create nested routing with a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, polymorphic-associations

I have three models: majors, careers, schools.  You can add a review for each of them. The associations look like this:

Major.rb, School.rb, Career.rb

> has_many :reviews, as :reviewable

Review.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
```

User.rb

> has_many :reviews

My routes look like this:

```
resources :majors, :schools, :careers do 
  resources :reviews
end
```

I want to be able to show all reviews related to a specific major when you go to a url like this: majorfinder.com/majors/major-name/reviews  But it is showing the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Reviews#index

Showing /Users/lauraleeflores/Sites/rails/mattan/app/views/reviews/_review.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `review_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd788ee3b28>:0x007fd78a9d6930>
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
2:   <tr>
3:     <td><%= review.review %></td>
4:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', polymorphic_path([review.reviewable, review]) %></td>
5: 
6:     <% if current_user == review.user %>
7:      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_major_review_path(review) %></td>
```

I have now fixed the problem and for anyone with the same problem this is how it was resolved:

The problem was in my controller and links.

Here's my updated review controller:

```
def index
  @reviews = @reviewable.reviews
end

def show
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.build
  @review.user = current_user
end

def edit 
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.find(params[:id])
  raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Access Denied") if @review.user != current_user
end

def create
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.build(params[:review])
  @review.user = current_user
end 

def update
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.find(params[:id])
  raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Access Denied") if @review.user != current_user
end

def destroy
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.find(params[:id])
  @review.destroy
  raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Access Denied") if @review.user != current_user
end
```

And then here's part of my reviews index page:

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= review.review %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', major_review_path(@reviewable, review) %></td>

    <% if current_user == review.user %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_major_review_path(@reviewable, review) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete', major_review_path(@reviewable, review), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <% end %>    
  </tr>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'New Review', new_major_review_path %>
```

Here's part of my show page:

```
<p>
  <b>Review:</b>
  <%= @review.review %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Review Profile Name:</b>
  <%= @review.user.profile_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Review User ID:</b>
  <%= @review.user %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Current User</b>
  <%= current_user %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Major that this review is for:</b>
  <%= @review.reviewable %>
</p>

<% if current_user == @review.user %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_major_review_path(@reviewable) %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', major_reviews_path %>
```

Here's my new review form using simple_form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@reviewable, @review]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :review %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope that helps someone that was in the same situation as me!

Comment: `major_review_path(review.reviewable, review)`

Comment: I tried major_review_path.  When I do that I get the following error: Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"reviews"}

Comment: of course, you have to pass the `major` object and `review` object to let ActionDispatch recognize your path. As for me, i prefer polymorphic routes instead: `polymorphic_path([review.reviewable, review])`

Comment: I can see the benefits of doing a polymorphic_path - it's easier to read and I know immediately a lot more about that link.  I updated my question with the polymorphic_path in the link.

Comment: try `simple_form_for([@review.reviewable, @review])`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  I updated the error in my question to show what error it results in.

Comment: And again, your @review object doesn't have reviewable object. Show the controller code first. All named routes have to know particular objects (or ids) to generate the path string.

Comment: I updated my question to include my reviews controller.

Comment: We're really close!  I updated my question above with update #3 to show the errors I'm getting now.  I also updated my reviews controller with your helpful suggestions under update #2.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that one or more instance from @reviews collection has no `reviewable` object.

That is why `polymorphic_path([review.reviewable, review])` tries to call `review_path` (because `review.reviewable` returns `nil`)

UPDATE:

Review controller:

```
before_filter :reviewable

def reviewable
  @reviewable = if params[:major_id]
    Major.find(params[:major_id])
  elsif params[:school_id]
    School.find(params[:school_id])
  elsif params[:career_id]
    Career.find(params[:career_id])
  end
end

def index
  @reviews = @reviewable.reviews
end

def show
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.build
  @review.user = current_user
  # @review = current_user.reviews.new
  # @review.reviewable = @reviewable
end

def create
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.build(params[:review])
  @review.user = current_user
  # @review = current_user.reviews.new(params[:review])
  # @review.reviewable = @reviewable
  ... save etc
end 

def edit 
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.find(params[:id])
  raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Access Denied") if @review.user != current_user
end

def update
  @review = @reviewable.reviews.find(params[:id])
  raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Access Denied") if @review.user != current_user
end
```

app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@reviewable, @review]) do |f| %> # or <%= simple_form_for([@review.reviewable, @review]) do |f| %>
...
```

Now try get the page:

```
majorfinder.com/majors/major-name/reviews

majorfinder.com/majors/major-name/reviews/new

majorfinder.com/majors/major-name/reviews/review_id/edit
```

Was it that you looking for? :)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!  I realize I need to add some reviews so this error is resolved.  I've updated my question again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and thoroughness!!  majorfinder.com/majors/major-name/reviews/new works great.  I run into a problem when trying to submit the review.  This is the error I run into: NoMethodError in ReviewsController#create

undefined method `review_url' for #<ReviewsController:0x007f9ba6cd8e28>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!  It's working great.  Thank you for all the time you took to help me!